# How to sum seven days from today in google script?

Tags: javascript, date, google-apps-script

I have the script below that is almost complete except that instead of adding seven days from today, it's adding seven days from eight days ago and I don't see why. Instead of getting May 23, 2020 (if ran May 16, 2020) it's giving me May 15, 2020. I've looked through it plenty of times and don't see the error.

Thoughts?

```
function emailAlert() {
  // today's date information
  var today = new Date();
  var todayMonth = today.getMonth() + 1;
  var todayDay = today.getDate();
  var todayYear = today.getFullYear();

  // 1 week from now
  var oneweeksFromToday = today;
  oneweeksFromToday.setDate(oneweeksFromToday.getDate() + 7);
  var oneweeksMonth = oneweeksFromToday.getMonth() + 1;
  var oneweeksDay = oneweeksFromToday.getDate();
  var oneweeksYear = oneweeksFromToday.getYear();

  // 1 month from now
  var oneMonthFromToday = new Date(todayYear, todayMonth, todayDay);
  var oneMonthMonth = oneMonthFromToday.getMonth() + 1;
  var oneMonthDay = oneMonthFromToday.getDate();
  var oneMonthYear = oneMonthFromToday.getYear();

  // getting data from spreadsheet
  var sheet = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSheet();
  var startRow = 2; // First row of data to process
  var numRows = 100; // Number of rows to process

  var dataRange = sheet.getRange(startRow, 1, numRows, 999);
  var data = dataRange.getValues();

  //looping through all of the rows
  for (var i = 0; i < data.length; ++i) {
    var row = data[i];

    var expireDateFormat = Utilities.formatDate(
      new Date(row[6]),
      'ET',
      'MM/dd/yyyy'
    );

    var dueDateFormat = Utilities.formatDate(
      new Date(row[5]),
      'ET',
      'MM/dd/yyyy'
    );


    // email information
    var subject = '';
    var message =
      ' Good morning' + ', this is a friendly reminder that invoice ' + row[0] + ' is scheduled to be due on '+ dueDateFormat + '.' + ' Please send your payment to... ' +
      expireDateFormat + '.';

    //expiration date information
    var expireDateMonth = new Date(row[6]).getMonth() + 1;
    var expireDateDay = new Date(row[6]).getDate();
    var expireDateYear = new Date(row[6]).getYear();

   //checking for 1 week from now

    Logger.log('1 weeks month, expire month' + oneweeksMonth + expireDateMonth);
    if (
      expireDateMonth === oneweeksMonth &&
      expireDateDay === oneweeksDay &&
      expireDateYear === oneweeksYear
    ) {
      var subject =
        'Project reminder: ' +
        row[0] +
          ' is scheduled to begin on '+ dueDateFormat;
      MailApp.sendEmail('jgom839@gmail.com', subject, message);
      Logger.log('2 weeks from now');
    }

    //checking for 1 month from now
    if (
      expireDateMonth === oneMonthMonth &&
      expireDateDay === oneMonthDay &&
      expireDateYear === oneMonthYear
    ) {
      var subject =
        'A license is expiring in 1 month: ' +
        row[7] +
        ' - ' +
        expireDateFormat;
      MailApp.sendEmail('jgom839@gmail.com', subject, message);
      Logger.log('1 month from now');
    }
  }
}
```

Comment: I surely believe you can solve it yourself by putting a `Logger.log` after every block, and analyse which part of it is creating the problem. That will narrow down your problem.

Comment: `var oneweeksFromToday = today;` doesn't copy *today*, it creates a second reference to the same date object, so all the actions you perform on *oneweeksFromToday* are being performed on *today*.

Comment: Both *oneweeksYear* and *oneMonthYear* use *getYear* instead of *getFullYear* so their value is 120 not 2020. Hence `expireDateYear === oneMonthYear` resolves to `2020 === 120` which is false. Dunno if that's your 8 day issue, but it's certainly **an** issue. :-)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Just figured out the issue, first let me say I'm sorry since it was my mistake due to not sharing my sheet to begin with. I should have been referencing column [5] not [6] like I have above.

I do have a question though, if I want this to only apply to sheet named "Client Invoices", tab "Upcoming Invoices" and no other tabs, what change do i need?

Comment: var sheet = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet().getSheetByName('Client Invoices')

Answer (score 1):

I always set the `today` back to `new Date()` whenever I'm working with more than one date. 
How about trying it like this

```
    function emailAlert() {
  // today's date information
  var today = new Date();
  var todayMonth = today.getMonth() + 1;
  var todayDay = today.getDate();
  var todayYear = today.getFullYear();

  // 1 week from now
  var today = new Date();
  var oneweeksFromToday =  new Date(today.setDate(today.getDate() + 7));
```

Answer (score -1):

A week from Today and a Month From Today

```
var dt=new Date();
var weeklater=new Date(dt.getFullYear(),dt.getMonth(),dt.getDate()+7);
var monthlater=new Date(dt.getFullYear(),dt.getMonth()+1,dt.getDate());
Logger.log(dt);
Logger.log(weeklater);
Logger.log(monthlater);
```

Logs

```
[20-05-17 00:11:28:311 MDT] Sun May 17 00:11:28 GMT-06:00 2020
[20-05-17 00:11:28:315 MDT] Sun May 24 00:00:00 GMT-06:00 2020
[20-05-17 00:11:28:318 MDT] Wed Jun 17 00:00:00 GMT-06:00 2020
```

Comment: This doesn't explain why the OP has their issue or how your code solves it.

Comment: I disagree I think it does

Comment: I have made changes and ran through everyone's suggestions and I still get the same results.

Comment: Please share your modified code, I'll take a look at it.

Comment: I'd also like to take a look at an image of your spreadsheet .